# Why do you use ToString() when using dates?

Tags: c#, tostring

I am learning C# with Microsoft Academy and during the lesson on dates and times the maker of the video used the `ToString` method on the date.
For example:

```
DateTime myValue = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(myValue.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

When I deleted the `ToString` method I got the same result, I assume it's for data uses but isn't it better to keep it as it is instead of turning it to `string`?

Comment: I think it was out of habit. Because `WriteLine()` logically calls `obj.ToString()` itself.

Comment: `ToString` defines the display format of the date when presenting it as text. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I'm guessing that because it's for teaching, the call is explicit so that whoever is reading understands that there is a `ToString()` method available on all objects that provides the `string` representation of that object.

Comment: If you don't include it, WriteLine will automatically convert the date into a string for you, because that's the logic thing to do if you want to display it. If you do include it, it a) makes the code a little bit clearer, as Lunyx mentions, and b) optionally allows you to specify the exact format in which the date will be printed. So "better" is subjective - it depends on the purpose of the code.

Comment: Agree with @RufusL, `ToString` with format. For me, in Poland allows format as I wish, not as system locale is (randomly) configured. I thing for no-US programmers good idea

Comment: @Steve - the *compiler* isn't inserting a `ToString` call at all. This resolves to a call to the `WriteLine(Object)` overload (which *doesn't* require a string parameter) and then *that method* calls `ToString`.

Comment: As far as whether you *should* use it in real code, my preference would be no. It's going to cause me to scan that line of code and think about why ToString was being called. Then I'll stop and wonder, "Was the developer thinking about putting a date format here?" Admittedly, it's a small thing, but the small things matter in large code bases.

Comment: @Joel6256 not quite true. There's an overload of WriteLine which accepts an object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx (credit the answer below, or you could easily have looked it up before commenting to check if you were correct or not). Equally the "Write" method is also overloaded: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx . The difference between Write and WriteLine is not the arguments they accept, it's...well actually the clue's in the name, really, you can figure it out :-)

Comment: @ADyson 
the page was not loaded. but thanks :]

Comment: I convert things because back in the day I learnt typed languages where you couldnt add a date and a string and have the compiler work out to convert it for you, so, I am generally explicit in all.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably for teaching purposes to show that the `string` is gotten from `myValue.ToString()` instead of relying on `Console.WriteLine()` to convert it for you. The conversion might be unknown to beginners and it's explicitly shown that the `string` is gotten from `.ToString()`.

Just writing `Console.WriteLine(myValue);` might lead new learners to include objects without creating their `ToString()` first and then calling their .`ToString()`.

Below shows an example:

```
public void ShowExample()
{
    DateTime myValue = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(myValue.ToString()); // 5/1/2018 10:14:20 AM

    Foo myFoo= new Foo(); // Has no ToString method
    Console.WriteLine(myFoo); // ConsoleApplication.Foo
    Bar myBar = new Bar(); // Has custom ToString method
    Console.WriteLine(myBar); // Hi I'm from ToString()
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Foo
{
    int val = 9;
}

public class Bar
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Hi I'm from ToString()";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. This is why we see questions on Stack Overflow from people asking why they keep getting `System.Array` on the console. Someone didn't learn to be specific about their type formats.

Answer (score 4):

It works without `.ToString()` because `Console.WriteLine()` has an [overload that accepts an `Object` argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx). Since *everything* derives from `Object`, and `Object` has it's own `ToString()` method, if there's no better match this version of the method can accept *anything* and try to print it.

You can think of the overloaded method like this:

```
public static void WriteLine(object value)
{
    WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

... such that this overload in turn calls [the `string` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx).

.Net is a strongly-typed platform. It pays to have an awareness of what types you're dealing with for every portion of a statement.

For `DateTime` values, they are not stored internally in a human-readable format. If you want to see a nice "`5/1/2018`" or "`2018-05-01`" value when you print to the Console, those are *strings*, and you need to convert the `DateTime` to a `string` in some way. Doing this in your code, rather than letting the Object overload handle it, makes it easier to come back and be specific about what format you want. But either version is really "okay".

Answer (score 1):

The method `Console.WriteLine()` has many overloads. One of them is `Console.WriteLine(string s)`. You are using it in your first example. It prints the string argument passed directly.

Another overload is `Console.WriteLine(object o)`. It accepts any instance (since every type is derived from `object`) and calls the `Object.ToString()` method internally, and then prints the resulting string. Every type derived from `object` inherits the `ToString()` method and can override it, as `DateTime` does.  That's why you can remove the `ToString()` in your second example.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `ToString()` is being called, nor does it answer the question of why not just use it without the `ToString()`.

Comment: @Lunyx better now?